# How to load bar graph from excel to matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, bar-chart

I have plotted a bar graph in excel. How do I load that bar graph from Excel to Matlab and plot it in Matlab ? I tried searching everything but no luck.

Any help is highly appreciated

Here's a code sample from what I've tried so far:

```
fileName='Book1.xlsx'; 
aa=xlsread(fileName); 
xv=aa(:,1); 
vb=aa(:,8); 
plot(xv,vb)
```

Comment: You want load the plot or the data?

Comment: @Rcoster I have actually plotted using the excel sheet . Now I want the same plot on to my Matlab so how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think loading an Excel graph into MATLAB is possible, but you can certainly load the data using [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html). After that, it's just a matter of using [`bar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html), [`barh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barh.html), or [`bar3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) to create a bar graph in MATLAB.

From what I understand from your supplied code, you're trying to plot a bar chart with x and y values, [similar to this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#btj3hs7-1) supplied by Mathworks.

Given your variables `xv` and `vb`, try using `bar(xv,vb)` instead of `plot(xv,vb)`.

If you need to sort `xv` to be in order, try:

```
[xv, idx] = sort(xv);
vb = vb(idx);
bar(xv,vb)
```

Comment: Did it throw an error? How far into the process did you get? Did you use xlsread successfully? If you post your code, it would be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: fileName='Book1.xlsx';
     aa=xlsread(fileName);
     xv=aa(:,1);  
     vb=aa(:,8);
     plot(xv,vb)

This is just a small piece of code ! where I tried to read the excel file. It did not through any error or anything.I needed the plot and It did not work. Well I am not sure where I went wrong

Comment: I have actually plotted using the excel sheet . Now I want the same plot on to my Matlab so how do I do that ? but the bar plot what I plotted in excel is different from what I plotted from Matlab. THe plot in excel is the correct one

Comment: @VinithpNair I can't help you any further without actually seeing what you want the plot to look like. Did you try using the bar command instead of the plot command?

Comment: I understand ! but I am asking in general whether it is possible to get a bar chart in matlab just the same way what was seen in Excel ?

Comment: You should be able to edit the bar series properties such as color, spacing, etc., to look like the Excel graph.

Comment: The example is almost the correct one except X is random. For example X=30 50 52 53 54 57 ..... so what can be done about this ?